# Effect of killing a long running rm command

Tags: linux, rm

Today I deleted a 50gb file stored on an ext3 filesystem using the `rm` command. It took `rm` almost 40 minutes of intense I/Os to release all the blocks. From what I see from other sources, that's the time it takes to release all the blocks used by the file. What would have happened if someone killed the `rm` process in the middle. Could this have caused a filesystem corruption, with some blocks that couldn't be reclaimed as free space anymore?

Comment: linux rm would usually remove files from the journal, but not from the disk. I find it odd it took so long. regardless rm should be safe to kill. for nicer io you can use `ionice -c2 -n7 rm bob1234.txt` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i.e. requiring `fsck`).  No filesystem inconsistency is necessary.

Yes, block release will happen after unlink.  But this process will not be interruptible.

[`ext2_evict_inode`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext2/inode.c?v=4.7#L1053) ->

```
__ext2_truncate_blocks ->
ext2_free_branches -> (for loop)
sb_bread ->
wait_on_buffer ->
```

`wait_on_bit_io(&bh->b_state, BH_Lock, TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);`

Above example is for `ext2`, I thought it'd be simpler to look at.  `ext3` is not going to be any different...

`ext4` should be faster though.  The use of extents should avoid the need for [triple-indirect blocks](https://lwn.net/Articles/187321/).  (Article describes adding extents to ext3, but Linus balked and said to bump the version number to ext4 first).  I expect the time updating bitmaps would be the same, but those are much more compact than the block pointers.